# Google Photos alternative

Tags: android, file-management, photography

I am looking for a Google Photos alternative because I don't really like the tag system.

Problem

- I cannot organize photos nicely using albums
- I can only add photos to albums but I cannot move photos to albums
- When I delete photos in albums, they are not deleted in the list of
  photos

Requirements

- When a photo is deleted in albums, it's also deleted in the system
- Large storage space
- An Android app

Optional

- Allow users to move (not add) photos to albums

Answer (score 2):

How about [flickr](https://www.flickr.com/)?

- Has an [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.yahoo.mobile.client.android.flickr)
- plenty of space (1T)
- when deleting photo, it will warn you about permanently delete

optionally, can organise photos in albums.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to organize local photos you can use https://github.com/k3b/APhotoManager/ which is available on fdroid.

pros:

- can be used as a replacement for the android stock gallery
- can copy/move photos to different folders (=?Albumms?) in single or multiselection mode
- can delete photos
- support for tagging and geotagging
- free and open source

contras:

- only support for local photos
- not available in goolge play store

Note: I am the author of APhotoManager

Answer (score -1):

Dropbox can store pictures along with other files, like documents. It has an Andriod app. If you refer friends to Dropbox, you get free storage. Onedrive is nice too, however, I don't know if it has an Andriod app.